# Problem with ssl configuration in Quarkus project when deploying in Docker

Tags: java, quarkus

Goodnight.
I am new to Quarkus and I am currently deploying my own service for my company, which consumes a DB and returns information. The issue that I present is that I am working with self-signed ssl certificates, and I am applying my configuration of the self-signed certificate through the application.properties file (just like in spring boot):

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.28.2.xxx:1522/IVR
quarkus.datasource.username=xxxx
quarkus.datasource.password=xxxxxxxxx

quarkus.ssl.native=true

quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=srvdevrma1.jks
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file-type=JKS
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-password=service123
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-key-alias=srvdevrma1

quarkus.swagger-ui.path=swaggerui

mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.title=Example API
%dev.mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.title=Example API (development)
%test.mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.title=Example API (test)
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.version=1.0.1
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.description=Just an example service
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.termsOfService=Your terms here
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.contact.email=techsupport@example.com
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.contact.name=Example API Support
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.contact.url=http://exampleurl.com/contact
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.license.name=Apache 2.0
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.license.url=https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
```

I currently have my self-signed .jks file at the level of my directory where my application.properties file is located:

[image]

I run my native build with no problems:

```
./mvnw package -Pnative
```

[image]

I create my native image using Dockerfile.native:

```
####
# This Dockerfile is used in order to build a container that runs the Quarkus application in native (no JVM) mode.
#
# Before building the container image run:
#
# ./mvnw package -Pnative
#
# Then, build the image with:
#
# docker build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.native -t quarkus/code-with-quarkus .
#
# Then run the container using:
#
# docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 quarkus/code-with-quarkus
#
###
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.5
WORKDIR /work/
RUN chown 1001 /work \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /work \
    && chown 1001:root /work
COPY --chown=1001:root target/*-runner /work/application

ENV TZ="America/Caracas"
EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Docker Build Command:

```
 docker build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.native -t codigo-puk:v1 .
```

However, when I go to lift my container I get the following error:

[image]

```
2022-06-05 20:40:59,686 INFO  [io.qua.sma.ope.run.OpenApiRecorder] (main) Default CORS properties will be used, please use 'quarkus.http.cors' properties instead
2022-06-05 20:40:59,690 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Failed to start application (with profile prod): java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: srvdevrma1.jks
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:218)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:380)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:432)
        at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:422)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:160)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.getFileContent(VertxHttpRecorder.java:890)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.createKeyStoreOptions(VertxHttpRecorder.java:870)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.createSslOptions(VertxHttpRecorder.java:791)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.doServerStart(VertxHttpRecorder.java:626)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.startServer(VertxHttpRecorder.java:302)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.VertxHttpProcessor$openSocket1866188241.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.VertxHttpProcessor$openSocket1866188241.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:103)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:67)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
        at com.tmve.customer.ServiceCustomMain.main(ServiceCustomMain.java:10)
```

It seems that with the profile prod I can't see the srvdevrma1.jks file, how is it done in this case, should I copy it when creating the image?

Comment: No screenshots of code or messages -- copy/paste text and format as code.

Comment: Can you try to put in your application.properties `quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=classpath:/srvdevrma1.jks`

Comment: @FelipeWindmoller 
In the end, I solved adding the certificate in the image using the command ADD srvdevrma1.jsk /work/srvdevrma1.jks and placing the respective path in the application.properties, just like compiling natively